# Vue problems convert options API to Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue component written using options API, and it's working as intended. When the user selects an image, it is displayed on the screen.

I am trying to convert this to using composition API, but it's not showing the image.

This is the original component:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'imageUpload',
  data() {
    return {
          imageUrl: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(e) {
      const file = e.target.files[0]
      this.imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    }
  }
} 
</script>

<template>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="onChange" />
    <div id="preview">
      <img v-if="imageUrl" :src="imageUrl" />
    </div>
  </template>
```

This is how I'm trying to convert it to composition, by using `ref` and then referring to the variables with `.value`? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

let imageURL = ref(null);

const onChange=(e) =>{
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  imageURL.value = file;
}

</script>

<template>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="onChange" />
    <div id="preview">
      <img v-if="imageUrl.value" :src="imageUrl.value" />
    </div>
  </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.value` only in the `<script>`. In the template, Vue will unref if automatically:

```html
<img v-if="imageUrl" :src="imageUrl" />
```

Also, I think you still have to create an URL for your file:

```
    onChange(e) {
      const file = e.target.files[0]
      imageUrl.value = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    }
```

Comment: I can see the file name once selected, but not the image itself. I am getting a vue warning that `imageUrl` is accessed but not rendered - is that related to not seeing the image? ***Edit, it was a stupid mistake - inconsistence casing on `URL` and `Url`